# Rails/Ruby & race conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

While I tried to google something, I found that all materials are about race conditions when rails app accesses DB.

But I have another issue, but not sure if it is race condition. Here is small method, which caches for a while user entry in case he accidentally reloads page/etc.

```
def redis_store(invalid_entries)
  if $redis.exists("invalid_entries_ids")
    id = $redis.incr("invalid_entries_ids")
  else
    id = 0
  end
  $redis.multi do
    if invalid_entries[:invalid].any?
       invalid_entries[:invalid].each do |entry|
        $redis.set("invalid_entries_ids", id, ex: 600)
        $redis.rpush("invalid_entries_attr:#{id}", entry[0])
        $redis.rpush("invalid_entries_errors:#{id}", entry[1])
        $redis.expire("invalid_entries_attr:#{id}", 600)
        $redis.expire("invalid_entries_errors:#{id}", 600)
       end
    end
    if invalid_entries[:list_error]
      $redis.set("list_error:#{id}", invalid_entries[:list_error], ex: 600)
    end
  end
  id
end
```

So basically redis `incr` is race condition safe (also in case of false I use plain ruby), but between that moment and `$redis.set("invalid_entries_ids", id, ex: 600)` there is some gap, in which two users invoking this method around same time can probably cause loosing one entry or something like this (I suppose).

But is there any approach to lock this method until executed? Or something like this? Or I'm misunderstand something?